# Checking array for duplicate objects - Equals() or Method?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, equals

I am learning C# on my own and am stuck on an exercise.  I need to ensure that no duplicate OrderNumbers are entered into my order array.  I think the idea of the exercise was to use Equals() however, I could not figure out how to get it to work.  I haven't learned anything too fancy yet.  Would Equals() be better than using a method for this?  Also, I am not sure how to call the method so I see the true or false values. If a duplicate is found, it should loop and ask user to re-enter.  Thanking you in advance as I am really frustrated... I so need a mentor!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Order[] order = new Order[3];
        int orderNumber;  // hold temp value until object is created
        string customerName;
        int qtyOrdered;

        for (int x = 0; x < order.Length; ++x) //to fill array
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Order Number: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out orderNumber); // put order number in temp

            if (order[x] != null) 
            {
                if (IsOrderNumberInUse(orderNumber, order) == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate order number");
                }
            }
                GetData(out customerName, out qtyOrdered);
                order[x] = new Order(orderNumber, customerName, qtyOrdered);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

   //METHOD TO CHECK FOR DUPLICATES
    private static bool IsOrderNumberInUse(int orderNumber, Order[] orders)
    {
        foreach (Order order in orders)
        {
            if (order.OrderNumber == orderNumber)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // If orderNumber was not found
        return false;
    }

    static void GetData(out string customerName, out int qtyOrdered)
    {
        //Console.Write("Enter Order Number: ");
        //int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out orderNumber);
        Console.Write("Enter Customer Name: ");
        customerName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Quantity Ordered: ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out qtyOrdered);
    }

    class Order
    {
        private const double PRICE = 19.95;
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public int QtyOrdered { get; set; }

        public double totalPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return QtyOrdered * PRICE;
            }
        }

        public Order(int orderNumber, string customer, int qty)  // Constructor
        {
            OrderNumber = orderNumber;
            CustomerName = customer;
            QtyOrdered = qty;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("\n" + GetType() + "\nCustomer: " + CustomerName + "\nOrder Number: " + OrderNumber +
                "\nQuantity:  " + QtyOrdered + "\nTotal Order:  " + totalPrice.ToString("C2"));
        }

        public override bool Equals(object x)
        {
            bool isEqual;

            if (this.GetType() != x.GetType())
                isEqual = false;
            else
            {
                Order temp = (Order)x;
                if (OrderNumber == temp.OrderNumber)
                    isEqual = true;
                else
                    isEqual = false;
            }
            return isEqual;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return OrderNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying not to use Lists as I have learned them yet and my next two exercises are connected to this one.  I'm afraid if I use Lists, I will be even more lost.  I am getting null errors and need help fixing them.  Here is my code.  Would using Equals be a better approach than the one that I am currently struggling with?  Thank you for your patience...

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Order [] orders  = new Order [3];
        int tempOrderNumber;
        string tempCustomerName;
        int tempQtyOrdered;

        for (int x = 0; x < orders.Length; ++x)  // fill list
        {
            tempOrderNumber = AskForOrderNumber(orders);
            GetData(out tempCustomerName, out tempQtyOrdered);
            orders[x] = new Order(tempOrderNumber, tempCustomerName, tempQtyOrdered);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int AskForOrderNumber(Order [] orders)
    {
        int tempOrderNumber;
        Console.Write("Enter Order Number: ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempOrderNumber);

            if (orders[0] !=null && IsOrderNumberInUse(tempOrderNumber, orders) == true) //Check for duplicates
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Duplicate order number");
                AskForOrderNumber(orders);
            }
            return tempOrderNumber;
    }

    static void GetData(out string tempCustomerName, out int tempQtyOrdered)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Customer Name: ");
        tempCustomerName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Quantity Ordered: ");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempQtyOrdered);
    }

    private static bool IsOrderNumberInUse(int tempOrderNumber, Order[] orders)
    {
        foreach (Order order in orders)
            {
            if (order.OrderNumber == tempOrderNumber)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
    }

    class Order
    {
        private const double PRICE = 19.95;
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public int QtyOrdered { get; set; }

        public double totalPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return QtyOrdered * PRICE;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("\n" + GetType() + "\nCustomer:  " + CustomerName + "\nOrder Number:  " + OrderNumber +
                "\nQuantity:  " + QtyOrdered + "\nTotal Order:  " + totalPrice.ToString("C2"));
        }

        public Order(int orderNumber, string customerName, int qtyOrdered)
        {
            OrderNumber = orderNumber;
            CustomerName = customerName;
            QtyOrdered = qtyOrdered;
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object x)
        {
            bool isEqual;

            if(this.GetType() != x.GetType())
                isEqual = false;
            else
            {
                Order temp = (Order) x;
                if(OrderNumber == temp.OrderNumber)
                    isEqual = true;
                else
                    isEqual = false;
            }
            return isEqual;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return OrderNumber;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question ? why do you have to use equals ? do you have any problem with your current approach?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I was wondering if Equals is better than creating a method.  My current approach does not work.  I can enter equals and it doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem, I would suggest you use a [`List<Order>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), because lists are resizable I believe they will be a better choice here.

Your current method doesn't work because you don't create `order[x]` until **after** you check for it.

**Using Lists/Fixed Code**

You should instead use the temporary `orderNumber`, however because the array is empty, you can also get null errors (which can be fixed) when checking for the first time, because of this I would again recommend a List.

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Order>(); //Orders list
int orderNumber; //Temporary order number
string customerName; //Temporary customer name 
int qtyOrdered; //Temporary quantity

for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) //Fill List
{
    Console.Write("Enter Order Number: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out orderNumber); //Parse order number

    if (IsOrderNumberInUse(orderNumber, orders) == true) //Check for duplicates
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate order number");
    }

    //Get data and add to list
    GetData(out customerName, out qtyOrdered);
    orders.Add(new Order(orderNumber, customerName, qtyOrdered));

}
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Asking the user again if input is invalid**

The example above shows my suggestions to fix your problem and use a `List`, but if you would like to go further and prompt the user to re-enter the value of it is in use. You can do this by creating a method to ask the user for input, and through recursion, ask them again if in use.

```
...
for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) //Fill List
{
    orderNumber = AskForOrderNumber(orders);

    //Get data and add to list
    GetData(out customerName, out qtyOrdered);
    orders.Add(new Order(orderNumber, customerName, qtyOrdered));

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static int AskForOrderNumber(List<Order> orders)
{
    int orderNumber;
    Console.Write("Enter Order Number: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out orderNumber); //Parse order number
    if (IsOrderNumberInUse(orderNumber, orders) == true) //Check for duplicates
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate order number");
        AskForOrderNumber(orders);
    }
    return orderNumber;
}
```

**Better method for checking for validation**

There is also nothing wrong with your current method for checking for duplicates, but it could be improved with [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx). (`using System.LINQ`)

```
private static bool IsOrderNumberInUse(int orderNumber, List<Order> orders)
{
     return orders.Any(o => o.OrderNumber == orderNumber);
}
```

Comment: There you go, I fixed the issues and provided some more options.

Comment: They are very simple, just like arrays, but you can add or remove elements from them. Check out my answer on [how to use lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954753/how-to-use-lists/17957654#17957654), or this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) on lists.

Comment: How do you fix getting null errors while checking for duplicate orders?

Comment: Can you show me your code? There shouldn't be any null errors anymore.

Comment: Fairly new to this forum, I added on to my original post, I hope that is proper procedure.

Comment: I see, that is why I suggested you switch to a `List`, it will prevent those errors.